# How to process received broadcast messages in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, shell, broadcast

I'm testing send/receive broadcast messages in Linux (using "wall" or "write" command). When I'm receiving a broadcast message, the terminal will display "Broadcast message from user@host (pts) (time stamp)", and the message.

My question is: **are there any ways that I can pass this received message into Shell scrip or C++, so I can use the script/program to removed the stuff I don't need?** For example, I only want "user:message". As long as my script/program is able to receive the message, I can modify it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can send a message without a banner by piping directly to the tty. Find the tty of everyone currently logged in with `who`. For example, sending a message to tty7:

```
echo "Hello World" | sudo tee /dev/tty7
```

From https://askubuntu.com/questions/220621/alternative-to-wall-talk-write